# Need help understanding module import errors

Tags: python, web2py, python-module

I'm trying to use the sendgrid Python API as a module in web2py. After testing it successfully from the command line, I dropped it into my modules folder, but as soon as I try to import sendgrid into my controller file, I get:

```
File "applications/test/modules/sendgrid/__init__.py", line 4, in
<module>
    del sendgrid, message NameError: name 'sendgrid' is not defined
```

Looking at the `__init__.py` file, I noticed they're doing * imports on the module level, which I've seen [cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3571514/165673) before, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

`sendgrid/__init__.py`:

```
from sendgrid import *
from message import *

del sendgrid, message

__version__ = "0.1.0"
version_info = (0, 1, 0)
```

**sendgrid api:**
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python

Comment: Can you show some working code where you got that error?

Comment: `import sendgrid` at the top of the controller file- that's it

Comment: Try this in that file:

`import sys; print sys.path; import sendgrid`

Comment: Colin- I can't print out of a web2py controller file- what are you trying to have me do?

Comment: He wants to see your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Yarin I'm trying to see what your path looks like. I just tried importing sendgrid myself from a file and the interpreter, and it works fine.

Comment: @Yarin Full traceback might help. Or at least where is the file that is being executed?

Comment: I'm importing it locally in web2py. In web2py environments `import` = import {applications.appname}.modules import`. Would PYTHONPATH be relevant?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the best practice for 3rd party modules is to install them via `pip` or `easy_install` (preferably in a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html)), if they're available on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sendgrid-python), rather than copying them somewhere onto your `PYTHONPATH`.

Try removing the sendgrid package from your modules folder and doing `pip install sendgrid-python` or `easy_install sendgrid-python` if `pip` isn't available.

Comment: Shakefu- " best practice for 3rd party modules is to install them via pip or easy_install" - Can you explain why this is preferred?

Comment: Because it actually installs the package via its `python setup.py install` to your `PYTHONPATH`, and runs the install scripts hooks necessary to install executable scripts, build C extensions, etc., that isn't done by just copying in a module.

Edit: Also, using a virtualenv is nice because it gives you a controlled package/dependency environment for each project, rather than installing every package system-wide (which may require root privileges). There are some instances where you can't use a virtualenv, but not many.

Comment: Because if you copy/paste the directory, you might end up with some problems, especially because "sengrid" will no longer be in the `PYTHONPATH`. You are tampering with the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Made this its own [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10761521/165673) - i need to understand this..