# Import variables from a config File

Tags: python, import

I have a script that have multiple files and a config file with all the variables store in one Python file.

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Config file:

[image: Config file]

If I try to run the main file which calls the `head` function imported, an error pops up saying that the config cannot be imported.

Imports:

[image: Imports image]

Comment: Please clarify: How do you run the main file? Which file is the head function in? Is there any detailed warning about the "cannot be imported" error?

Comment: I´m running the main file and this error pops up import * only allowed at module level

Comment: It appears that `import *` inside a function is prohibited intendedly. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571514/python-why-should-from-module-import-be-prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Functions folder has a **__init__.py** file. If your app executes from Main.py (ie if Main.py satisfies `__name__ == "__main__"`) therefore wherever you are in your app you could import the config like this:

```
from Functions.Config import *
```

## Edit:

However,`from module import *` is not recommended with local import. You could give an alias to the import and call `name.variable` instead of calling `name` directly.
Example:

```
def head():
    # import packages
    import Function.Config as conf
    print(conf.more_200)
head()
>>> 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax are wrong.

It is supposed to be `from Config import *` and not `import .Config import *`

Comment: HEllo, This error poop up import * only allowed at module level

Comment: That is because you put all of the imports in a function, which triggers a `SyntaxWarning` warning. To prevent this, put all of your imports on the top of your python file instead of in a function.

Comment: Both two codes can be valid syntactically. It just depends on whether it is inside a package to use relative imports or not. For ref: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports.

Comment: But if you do not want to do that, it's fine. Warning doesn't stop the program from executing.